# Why my myopia spectacles doesn't allow a person with normal eye to see clearly?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses, vision

I am a student of class 10. I have been taught that myopia spectacles (concave lenses) corrects the vision by forming a virtual object at the person's far point. But I am unable to figure out one thing. Here is the problem:

Suppose I am suffering from myopia and my far point is 80 cm. So, I will use a spectacles which will form a virtual object at 80 cm for an object which is kept at infinity.

Now if I give my spectacles to a friend with a normal vision. So, he can see an object kept at 80 cm clearly. But he won't see objects through my spectacles clearly.

When my friend uses the spectacles, his eyes will also see the virtual object formed at 80 cm. But how is it possible that he doesn't sees through it clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note your eye lens has more power than your friend.But for same virtual object your eye has minimum power possible so you do not have to strain our eyes.but your friend has to increase his power of lens by straining as it is not minimum power of his eyes.He can see bit if he strains his eye.

Comment: So what you are saying is that if he strains his eyes, then he will be able to see clearly.

Comment: @user12137152 yes